# What happens if i have ./ or ../ or .../ in my url?

Tags: http, url, encoding, https, escaping

Let's say we have Urls as shown below

1. http://localhost:8080/sample/url/./something?queryparam=something
2. http://localhost:8080/sample/url/../something?queryparam=something
3. http://localhost:8080/sample/url/.../something?queryparam=something

These are valid urls which will fetch some response.
But only the third Url gets hit correctly, the first two after hitting gets changed to

http://localhost:8080/sample/url/something?queryparam=something (it removed './')

http://localhost:8080/sample/url/something?queryparam=something (it removed '../')

But worked for the third url.

How is this escaping happening over here?

Answer (score 0):

The second one should actually be evaluated as:

http://localhost:8080/sample/something?queryparam=something

What you see here is the result of relative resolution, in particular https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#relative-dot-segments.

If you want literal "." or ".." in the URI, you'll have to percent-escape them.

Comment: Yes, the second one evaluates as you have commented.

Comment: Even if I Percent Encode them, it is behaving the same. I tried same Urls replacing . with percent encode dot -> %2E 
It worked only for the third Url.